# how to do passwordless ssh access to slave while starting services of hadoop in its multinod cluster..

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I've installed multinode cluster of hadoop. Now I am trying to do passwordless ssh access to slave. i.e. my problem is that,when I start services from master it asks me password to start every service, and takes much time to start it.If anyone has solution then please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate and copy RSA key from Namenode to all the Datanodes.

```
user@namenode:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Just press 'Enter' for any passphrase

```
user@namenode:~> ssh user@datanode mkdir -p .ssh
user@datanode's password:
```

Finally append namenode's new public key to user@datanode:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter datanode's password one last time:

```
user@namenode:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@datanoe 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
user@datanode's password:
```

You can test by

```
user@namenode:~> ssh user@datanode
```

Comment: @RSanket Do you have access to id_rsa.pub? Try doing using sudo.

Comment: @user3484461 such file is not present in the system, i'm using fedora 20..Currently i am able to start services on datanodes, so issue regarding denial of permission is solved, But still it is asking password while starting services on datanode....Now,I'm not sure about whether the problem is with that rsa key copying on datanode or else...if anyone find solution pls tell me....

Comment: @Piyush Yes I have access to id_rsa.pub

Comment: Try using `ssh-copy-id` to copy the namenode's public key to all the datanode's. The issue may be related to `authorized_keys` file permission, generally the permissions for `authorized_keys` should be `600`.